# Solution for two-variable integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have the following antiderivative and associated definite integral (with $n,t$ positive integers with $m \le n$, and $k$ an integer $\ge n$):

$$\int \biggl(\frac{1}{\left(n-t^2\right)^2+1}\biggr)^k \, dt$$

$$\int_1^n \biggl(\frac{1}{\left(n-t^2\right)^2+1}\biggr)^k \, dt$$

Can these be calculated? How?

Comment: Is $k$ an arbitrary real number?

Comment: Hi @Alexander. Sorry, I missed this off. See above.

Comment: See here for an anitderivative it seems complex https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive++%281%2F%28n-x%C2%B2-i%29*1%2F%28n-x%C2%B2%2Bi%29%29%5Ek